# GetResourceBindingDescByName in DirectX 11 can only get the first cbuffer

Tags: directx, shader, directx-11, hlsl

I'm learning DirectX 11 and have reached basic HLSL part. I want to use multiple constant buffers in vertex shader, so I need to find the correct `StartSlot` for `VSSetConstantBuffers`. I searched on Google and found that someone suggested using `GetResourceBindingDescByName`.

I tried `GetResourceBindingDescByName`, but found that it can only get the correct `StartSlot` for the first cbuffer. For example, in my vertex shader:

```
cbuffer Test1
{
    float4 a;
};

cbuffer Test2
{
    float4 b;
};
```

Now `GetResourceBindingDescByName("Test1", &bind_desc)` works correctly, but `GetResourceBindingDescByName("Test2", &bind_desc)` will fail (return `E_INVAILDARG`).

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Does b is used in your shader ? It may have been striped by the optimisation.

Comment: Thank you. I just use a in my shader. I add a reference to b in my shader code and the problem is solved. Can you answer this question so that I can mark it as the answer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reflection only contains symbols use by a shader. As confirmed in the comments, b was not use, and the problem is solve once b is referenced in the code and not strip away by an optimisation.